# Chronometer class not working in android pie API 28?

Tags: android, android-widget

My chronometer class is working fine till I tested my app with Android Pie (API 28). I am finding  no solution anywhere about it

```java
chronometer.setOnChronometerTickListener(new Chronometer.OnChronometerTickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChronometerTick(Chronometer chronometer) {
        xtime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - chronometer.getBase();

        if (xtime >= 1000 && xtime < 2000) {
            speechtextlayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            speechText.setText(getText(R.string.flbdy_easy_5_lipexfoliation_pomegranate_step5_audio1));

            releaseMediaPlayer();
            int result = mAudiomanager.requestAudioFocus(mAudioFocusChangeListner, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN_TRANSIENT);

            if (result == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_REQUEST_GRANTED) {
                audio = MediaPlayer.create(ctx, R.raw.fullbody_easy_5_lip_honey_st4_1_washwarm);
                audio.start();
                audio.setOnCompletionListener(mOncompletion);
            }
        } else if (xtime > 35000) {
            chronometer.stop();
            speechtextlayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: whats happening when you're running the code? any logs?

Comment: 06-07 00:34:02.276 8235-8375/skincare.facecare.fullbodycare.beautychallange.beauty.a30daybeautycare E/libc: Access denied finding property "persist.vendor.hwui.skia.reduce.overdraw.enabled"
06-07 00:34:02.267 8235-8235/skincare.facecare.fullbodycare.beautychallange.beauty.a30daybeautycare W/RenderThread: type=1400 audit(0.0:11656): avc: denied { map } for path="/dev/__properties__/u:object_r:vendor_default_prop:s0" dev="tmpfs" ino=16205 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app_27:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:vendor_default_prop:s0 tclass=file permissive=0